# Toogle state react react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to do a conditional rendering using hooks.
I use different component for each screen, and I would like to be able to toggle the state from the "parent" component using hooks.
How can I do this ?

```js
import React from "react";
import {
    useState
} from "react";
import "../App.css";

export default function Auth() {
    const [hasAccount, setHasAccount] = useState(false);
    const toogleHasAccount = () => {
        console.log("toogleHasAccount");
        setHasAccount((hasAccount) => !hasAccount);
    };

    if (hasAccount) {
        return <LoginScreen / > ;
    }
    return <SignUpScreen / > ;
}

function SignUpScreen() {
    return ( <
        div className = "App" >
        <
        div > SignUpScreen < /div> <
        button onClick = {
            this.toogleHasAccount()
        } > Toggle State < /button> <
        /div>
    );
}

function LoginScreen() {
    return ( <
        div >
        <
        div > LoginScreen < /div> <
        button onClick = {
            () => this.toogleHasAccount()
        } > Sign Out < /button> <
        /div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all instead of this:

```
const toogleHasAccount = () => {
   setHasAccount((hasAccount) => !hasAccount)};
```

You dont have to use function inside so do this:

```
const toogleHasAccount = () => {
   setHasAccount(!hasAccount)};
```

If you want to use function or other value from parent component you need to pass down props.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "../App.css";

export default function Auth() {
  const [hasAccount, setHasAccount] = useState(false);
  const toogleHasAccount = () => {
    console.log("toogleHasAccount");
    setHasAccount(!hasAccount);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {hasAccount ? (
        <LoginScreen />
      ) : (
        <SignUpScreen toogleHasAccount={toogleHasAccount} />
      )}
    </>
  );
}

function SignUpScreen({ toogleHasAccount }) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div> SignUpScreen </div>
      <button onClick={() => toogleHasAccount()}> Toggle State </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function LoginScreen({ toogleHasAccount }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div> LoginScreen </div>
      <button onClick={() => toogleHasAccount()}> Sign Out </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[React's official](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) documentation includes an easily written tutorial on how to use it.